# Can't get run my application after installation?

Tags: scripting, installation, nsis

I builded nsis script succesfully, but after installing, I can't run my application without admin privilegies. Anyone who knows what's a problem?

---

Thanks for answers. I found a bug in my application, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508327/cant-run-application-in-debug-folder-of-visual-studio-solution)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you just disable the run checkbox on the finish page. If you really need to start a app as non-admin, use the [UAC plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in)

Comment: As I understand this plugin is only for vista/7, however my application must run on XP also. Any suggestions? I'm really new in nsis ..

Comment: @Dastan No, it is for any version of windows (And has elevation handling on 2000+, pass through on NT4/9x)

Comment: Ok, Is there a ready-made examples? I would be very grateful. Or at least some reference to a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add this in the beginning of your installation script:

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin
```

This allow two parameters: admin or user, with admin execution level you may be able to start your application with admin privileges.